# gwt checkbox fire handler when setValue(true)

Tags: gwt, checkbox, handler, setvalue, valuechangelistener

I have a checkbox with a `valueChangeHandler` on it. It works when user check the checkbox.

For some reason, I need to set a value to this checkbox in my code, like this :

`checkbox.setValue(true)`, the checkbox is perfectly checked visually but my problem is that it doesn't fire my valueChangeHandler.

```
checkBox.setValue(true);

checkBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>() {
   @Override
   public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
     ...
   }
});
```

Is there another handler that can be fire when I set a value ? Or another way to dot this?

Thanks

**EDIT** : I also tried checkbox.setValue(true,true) but it doesn't work.

**RESOLVED** : the setValue MUST BE after the registration of the handler. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the difference between [`setValue(Boolean)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html#setValue(java.lang.Boolean)) vs. [`setValue(Boolean,boolean)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html#setValue(java.lang.Boolean,%20boolean))

```
checkBox.setValue(true, true);
```

Comment: nope, checkBox.setValue(true,true) doesn't work neither

Comment: That would mean that the checkbox value is already `true`. Or could it be a race condition between adding the event handler and calling `setValue`? Is the code really like you put it in the question (two lines next to each others)? Where is this code called from? In response to which event?

Comment: It finally works. But the checkBox.setValue(true, true) must absolutely be after the checkBox.addValueChangeHandler. Otherwise it doesn't work. Thanks